# Pdfsharp and margins when generating pdf

Tags: pdfsharp

I discovered something strange when I added margins to my document.
I am setting the pagesize to A4 (210x297mm) then I am adding left and top margin of 10mm (yes I am sure the calculation to point is right) and bottom and right marigins are 0.

What happens is that the document size of the generated pdf-file is 220x307mm.

What I have to do is, after setting the pagesize and setting the margins, is to recalculate the pagesize.

```
page.TrimMargins.Top    = top;
page.TrimMargins.Left   = left;
page.TrimMargins.Bottom = bottom;
page.TrimMargins.Right  = right;

page.Height = page.Height - page.TrimMargins.Top - page.TrimMargins.Bottom;
page.Width = page.Width - page.TrimMargins.Left - page.TrimMargins.Right;
```

I got it working, but is this the way it is supposed to work?

I also tried to set the margins before the page size, but no, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found some internal sample code. It seems adjusting the page size is not required when PDFsharp is used as in the sample.
First the trim margin `trim` is set for the `Setting` member of the instance of the `PdfDocument` class:

```
pdfDocument.Settings.TrimMargins.All = trim;
```

Later on, after creating a page, page.Width and page.Height are set without any adjustments.

Note: Using the `All` member applies the same trim margin to all four sides. It should work the same using individual values for individual sides.

Comment: Eh, you mean smaller, or? Because when adding trim margins it actually  grows in size.